# Initial condition of the millenium simulation

Tags: cosmology, computational-physics, simulations

I would like to know the initial conditions used for the [millenium simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Run). More specifically, I would like to know the amplitude of the initial power spectrum $\mathcal{A}$.

I have found the cosmological parameters, the power law slope of the initial power spectrum $n_s$ all from an internal link, but not $\mathcal{A}$, and this is also not described in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0504097). However, they provide $\sigma_8$, is there a way to extract $\mathcal{A}$ from $\sigma_8$ and $n_s$?

On top of this, should I expect the power spectrum as measured from a galaxy catalog generated from the millenium simulation (for instance [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0701407)) to be broadly compatible with a power spectrum as generated from some other package (for instance [cosmopower](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.03846))?

Comment: $\mathcal{A}\propto \sigma_8^2$ (at fixed $n_s$), but the precise relationship is obtained using a Boltzmann solver (the defunct CMBFAST is mentioned in the Millennium Simulation paper).